# Drupal translation from file

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, translation

Everything is fine with my Drupal (7.8) translation (English -> French) in a classic way but I guess the t() is based on SQL queries. How can I force Drupal to read those translations entries from a file rather than let it use the database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that without hacking core.

However, short translations are cached and you can use a different cache backend for that, for example Memcache or a File based cache.